# kubectl bash completion doesn't work in ubuntu docker container

Tags: bash, docker, autocomplete, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm using kubectl from within a docker container running on a Mac. I've already successfully configured the bash completion for kubectl to work on the Mac, however, it doesn't work within the docker container. I always get `bash: _get_comp_words_by_ref: command not found`.

The docker image is based on `ubuntu:16.04` and kubectl is installed via the line (snippet from the dockerfile)

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl && \
mv kubectl /usr/local/bin
```

`echo $BASH_VERSION` gives me `4.3.48(1)-release`, and according to apt, the `bash-completion`package is installed.

I'm using iTerm2 as terminal.

Any idea why it doesn't work or how to get it to work?

Comment: docker run -itd ubuntu:16.04
    docker exec -it <id> bash
    apt update && apt install -y curl
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl

Then when I source the bash completion, it's working for me.

    root@5d4fd8949ef0:/# source <(kubectl completion bash)

Comment: I tried to reproduce that, but for me, it still didn't work ...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Ok, I found it - I simply needed to do a `source /etc/bash_completion` before or after the `source <(kubectl completion bash)`.

Comment: Thanks @DonGiovanni - that fixed it for me too.  One would think that installing the `bash-completion` package would automatically ensure that any `BASH` shell would get this sourced, right? But, I guess that's asking for too much; it could be argued that I just wanted to have it installed but not make use of it - tsk., tsk.

Comment: [i get that the question is for Ubuntu]
For RHEL without bash-completion pre-installed:

Install using `yum install -y bash-completion`

and then source using `source /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`

followed by the actual command `source <(kubectl completion bash)`

Answer (score 2):

check .bashrc

enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
sources /etc/bash.bashrc).

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

A Linux container executed on macOS creates a separate environment and
yes, it looks like a thread from macOS shell, but it is not. Shell history,
properties, functions are a different story.
Moreover, if the container has no persistent volume mounted all of those parameters will be transisten and won’t survive container’s restart.

The approach to have bash completion of both of them - macOS and Ubuntu
Linux are similar, but require different steps to take:

macOS side - permanent support for kubectl bash completion:

use homebrew to install support:

```
brew install bash-completion
kubectl completion bash > $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/kubectl
```

Ubuntu container’s approach to have kubectl and bash completion support build in:

You can adapt this set of commands and use it in Dockerfile during the image preparation:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
apt-get update
apt-get install -y kubectl
echo 'source <(kubectl completion bash)' >> ~/.bashrc
```

If afterwards you or user executes /bin/bash in running container then you should get  completion working.

```
docker exec -it docker_image_id /bin/bash
```

this will start bash shell with the bash completion.

Comment: I tried to adapt that for the dockerfile, but ran into some problems. I then tried to do these steps manually within a running container:
`apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
apt-get update
apt-get install -y kubectl
echo 'source <(kubectl completion bash)' >> ~/.bashrc`

However, the bash completion still doesn't work.

Comment: Hm, on my Mac I installed not the package "bash-completion", but instead "bash-completion@2" via homebrew because it said that this version should be used for bash version > 4.1.  Could that cause problems?

Comment: In both cases you need to re-login current user. Did you do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. It works perfectly fine for macOS, but within the docker container, I still get the same error when trying to use auto complete.

Answer (score 0):

I united two top comments for Ubuntu 22.04

edit ~/.bashrc and add

```
source /etc/bash_completion
```

before

```
source <(kubectl completion bash)
alias k=kubectl
complete -o default -F __start_kubectl k
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

alias k='kubectl'
complete -F __start_kubectl k

alias kp='kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=wide'

source <(kubectl completion bash)
```